# strcpy function to copy string

Tags: c

I am trying to copy a string from an array of strings to another string variable using `strcpy`... What is the mistake here? Why is the output wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    int i;
    char cw[3][12];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        scanf("%s", &cw[i]);
    
    puts(cw[2]);
    char ch[12] = "hftiuh";
    puts(ch);
    strcpy(ch, cw[2]);
    puts(ch[12]);
}
```

input

```
hello
again 
there
```

this gives output

```
there
hftiuh
```

expected output

```
there
hftiuh
there
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&cw[i]` -> `cw[i]`

Comment: You write `strcpy(ch,cw[2]);` __and__ `scanf("%s",&cw[i]);`, why?

Comment: puts(ch[12]) is still wrong. You can't learn C by trial and error.

Comment: @methead and what does that have to do with `puts(ch[12]) ` being *wrong*? The `puts` function requires a `const char *` compatible argument. You're giving it (a) a `char` argument so it isn't compatible, and (b) indexing a fixed array out of range to acquire it. *It's wrong*.

Comment: It's just `puts(ch)`. You had that correctly two lines above.

Comment: Because `char *` is compatible with `const char *`; `char` is *not*. You managed to do it right two lines earlier. Whatever motivated you to author that, stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone...for just viewing my silly ques...and especially stark for telling that its wrong instead of telling how to correct, it helped...I found the answer, there was no compiler error just to clear most comments...i changed

```
puts(ch[12]);
```

to

```
puts(ch);
```

thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int  main()
{
    int i;
    char cw[3][12];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        scanf("%s",*(cw+i));
    puts(cw[2]);
    char ch[12]="hftiuh";
    puts(ch);
    strcpy(ch,cw[2]);
    puts(ch);
    return 0;
}
```